# How to disable intellisense database in visual studio python

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017

I accidently enabled `intellisense` database in a `visual studio 2017 python project` and i dont know how to disable it, Its taking a long time to refresh and i don't have time to wait for it, I tried searching for it in the options but couldn't find anything, I tried googling it too and i didn't find anything again.
 I can't do anything if it didn't refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same. Go to Tools > Options > Python > Experimental and select Use new style IntelliSense for environments.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/python-environments-window-tab-reference?view=vs-2017#intellisense-tab

Answer (score 1):

You can use:
Tools > Options > Python

[image]

See the first option. I am using Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.8.4